# How to store fresh coriander for future use, outside refrigerator, so that they don't lose their taste?

Tags: storage-method, herbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Store Fresh Herbs](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-to-store-fresh-herbs)

I have seen this thread: [How to Store Fresh Herbs](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-to-store-fresh-herbs), but I won't want to use a fridge neither I have any garden. All I have is the plastic bottle.

Comment: I believe suggestion 3 for that question covers that possibility: put the stems in water, and optionally cover the leaves with a plastic bag.

Comment: @BobMcGee for how much time will that remain edible? I want to preserve it for weeks.

Comment: If you want to keep it for weeks, perhaps you should leave it in the ground until you're ready :)

Comment: @Ray I said in my OP I don't have a garden. I have to purchase them from the market and they are NOT always available, specially in summer.

Comment: Sorry; just a failed attempt at some light humor. I've had some success with products like this: http://www.amazon.com/Debbie-Meyer-20317-Green-Bags/dp/B0011TMP3Y and this: http://www.evertfresh.com/?q=node/7

Comment: @Ray No that was NOT a failed attempt at humor ;) I DO understand _"dry humor"_ very well, that's my type :) Thanks for the links, I am not sure though whether they will be available in India somewhere.

Comment: Anisha: I believe the answers to the existing question cover the various methods fairly effectively. I've [summarized them in another answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-to-store-fresh-herbs/15654#15654) to make it easier to pick the technique that meets your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buying coriander whole rather than ground is probably your best bet. As is the case with allspice and coffee, they're bound to eventually lose flavor, likely to light/heat/moisture, fresh grinding will bring back some of the spark.

If you're using fresh from the garden coriander you're not out of options. There's [the floral option](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-to-store-fresh-herbs/3707#3707), and also [the same rules apply here for drying herbs](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3147/15) if you're willing to go down that route. If the fridge/freezer simply isn't an option, and having a bouquet of coriander isn't in the cards, then I would just hang them upside down in your basement/closet and then keep them in airtight containers away from direct light and heat.

Comment: I was NOT referring to the ground coriander here, I was talking about the fresh leaves, I fear they will attract fungus, if washed and then stores, should I put them under a fan for drying?

Comment: @Anisha you might add that into the question, there's [the floral option](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-to-store-fresh-herbs/3707#3707), but essentially [the same rules apply for drying herbs](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3147/15) if you're willing to go down that route. But if the fridge/freezer simply isn't an option, and having a bouquet of coriander isn't in the cards, then I would just hang them upside down in your basement/closet and then keep them in airtight containers away from direct light and heat.

Comment: So, hanging them for how long? Till they dry up completely? And how does hanging downwards help?

Comment: @Anisha Assuming you want to dry them, you hang them upside down until they dry up. I have always hung them upside down for the same reason you hang flowers upside down to try; they retain their shape. (And an old wives' tale?)

Comment: Thanks, do they retain their natural taste after they dry up completely?, and no I am not talking about scent, I am talking about taste.